# Why is this proof of False in the Calculus of Constructions not valid?

Tags: fake-proofs, lambda-calculus, automated-theorem-proving

So, this would be a definition of False in the Calculus of Constructions:

$$\bot = \forall x : \mathbf P . x$$

And, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions), this is an inference rule:

$${\Gamma \vdash A : K \qquad \Gamma , x : A \vdash B : L} \over {\Gamma \vdash (\forall x : A . B) : L}$$

Wouldn't this imply the following:

$$(\forall x : \bot . x) : \bot$$

Obviously this can't be the case, as this would provide a proof of $\bot$. Why is this proof incorrect though?

Additional context: I'm writing [an automated proof checker](https://github.com/aerkiaga/rooster) and the above term proves False, which makes the program useless since it results in inconsistent logic.

Comment: Could you add a link to the Wikipedia page talking about that inference rule?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco sorry for that, edited now.

Comment: $K$ and $L$ are stated to stand in for either $\mathbf{P}$ or $\mathbf{T}$. $⊥$ is not one of these.

Comment: @DanDoel thanks, that was an embarrassingly basic reading mistake... Indeed, the article states, several paragraphs above: "In the following, we use [...] $K , L$ to mean either $\mathbf {P}$ or $\mathbf {T}$."

Comment: @DanDoel I'm not familiar with this site, but wouldn't you like to present your comment as an answer?